# Trigger lightbox with javascript

Tags: jquery, lightbox2

I want to use this library: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

I can't attach `rel="lightbox"` to each image so I want to use jQuery to trigger the lightbox.

I was thinking about something like:

```
$('img').click(function(){
  //triger lightbox for this image
  //use self src as href
});
```

How can I trigger the lightbox for one image?

Comment: The lightbox uses the link on a thumbnail image to display the larger version. How would applying the effect to an image work?

Comment: The image is not a thumbnail i'm showing, it's just the large image width max-width and max-height attributes set. I want the lightbox to show the same image (the link should be the same as image src)

Comment: I don't think the lightbox you pointed to can do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the problem by wrapping the `img` tag in an `a` tag and triggering click on a after that.

```
$('img').click(function () {
    $(this).wrap('<a href="' + $(this).attr("src") + '" rel="lightbox" />');
    $(this).parent('a').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That plugin has to have the `rel="lightbox"` to work.
That's mentioned on the How to use

You can add that attribute with jquery using

```
$('img').attr('rel', 'lightbox');
```

You will need to add that line inside your document ready function.

If that still doesn't work for you then I'd suggest you use this other plugin

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/