# jquery on keypress to show lightbox

Tags: jquery, lightbox, keypress, keydown

I have jquery code that allow me to prompt when pressing ESC key, like this...

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) { 
    if (e.which == 27) {
        alert('esc pressed');
    }
});
```

});

My question is that when press ESC key I want to prompt with jquery lightbox, does any one know which light box that will works  when pressing ESC key!

And how do I can write that code to add any any lightbox code with above code!

AM

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820277/trigger-lightbox-with-javascript

Comment: @PedroEstrada, thanks for that sample, but still some help, i got idea from there like this... [code]$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) { 
    if (e.which == 27) {
        $(this).wrap('<a href="' + $(this).attr("src") + '" rel="lightbox" />');
    $(this).parent('a').trigger('click');
    }
}); }); , but I'm trying to figure out what to write in html code to make works with jquery! please help thanks.

Comment: No problem dude. I'm proud of you.